# scala regex: extract expression from string

Tags: regex, scala

I'd like to extract the expressions `${*}` from a String.

```
val example = "Hello ${foo.bar} World"
```

But the dollar sign and the curly brackets are part of the expression syntax, so I tried to escape it.

```
val expr = "\\$\\{[a-zA-Z0-9\\w]*\\}".r
```

But this won't work and `println` prints nothing:

```
for (ex <- expr.findAllMatchIn(example)) println(ex)
```

Anyone has an idea what's wrong? There exists a more elegant regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are not accounting for the `.` in `foo.bar`, do this instead:

```
\\$\\{[a-zA-Z0-9.\\w]*\\}             // allows for a . to also be in the string
```

For maximum flexibility, you can do:

`\\$\\{[^}]*.`

Comment: Thank you, """\$\{[^}]*.""".r works very well, it is also possible to extract multiple expressions. `val example2 = "hello ${foo.bar} world ${bar.foo}"`. Therefore I accept this answer. :)

Comment: Definitely got to rock the triple quotes, though. It makes it easier to spot mistakes.

Comment: You should definitly put more emphasis on the shortcommings of the first solution. It will only work if there are no repetitions of "}" . The second one would be the only safe way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simpler regex, and you can make it easier to read (avoiding the need for double escaping `\\`) by using triple-quotes:

```
val example = "Hello ${foo.bar} World ${bar.foo}"
                                              //> example  : String = Hello ${foo.bar} World ${bar.foo}

val expr = """\$\{.*?\}""".r                    //> expr  : scala.util.matching.Regex = \$\{.*?\}

for (ex <- expr.findAllMatchIn(example)) println(ex)
                                              //> ${foo.bar}
                                              //| ${bar.foo}
```

Comment: Thank you! `"""\$\{.*\}""".r` works very well, but if multiple expressions occour, it matches to much. For example `val example2 = "hello ${foo.bar} world ${bar.foo}"`.

Comment: Fixed - I have added a non-greedy modifier (`?`)